# How to plot a pair of functions as solid and dashed, but a list of those pairs as different colors, in one plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of pairs of functions:

```
fns = Table[{a*x, a*x^2}, {a, 5}]

{{x, x^2}, {2 x, 2 x^2}, {3 x, 3 x^2}, {4 x, 4 x^2}, {5 x, 5 x^2}}
```

What I would like to do is plot it so that the two functions in each of those *pairs* is the same color, but the first is solid and the second is dashed, and then have each *pair* be a different color than the others. So for example, it might be {{{Blue, Thick},{Blue, Dashed}},{{Red, Thick},{Red, Dashed}},...}.

If I simply do `Plot[fns, {x, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]`, it *does* make the first in each pair solid and the second dashed, but it also makes them different colors:

[image]

I know I could solve this by relying on the fact that they will be colored in the same order in different plots, and separating the first and second elements of each pair and plotting them separately:

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate@fns[[All, 1]], {x, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Thick];
p2 = Plot[Evaluate@fns[[All, 2]], {x, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Dashed];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

But this is messy, and you can actually already see that I had to use Show[] in the order p2, p1, because if I do it as p1, p2, it uses p1's smaller vertical range, which makes it different than just plotting them all together.

I know there must be a simple way but I've read the documentation for PlotStyle and searched for posts here and can't find it. How can this be done?

Comment: I'm thinking: no.
If it's any consolation, you can add `, PlotRange -> All` to the `Show[]`

Comment: @Feyre I can think of another way, basically constructing a list manually beforehand for PlotStyle, but it's also inelegant. That's good to know though, thanks.

Comment: I think your solution, with @Feyre's `PlotRange` recommendation, is probably the most elegant solution to this problem.  You could localize `p1` and `p2` if you don't like having the extra global variables.  Other than that, it seems short & sweet.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

```
fns = Table[{a*x, a*x^2}, {a, 5}];

cd = Flatten@Table[{
     Directive[ColorData[97, c], Thick],
     Directive[ColorData[97, c], Dashed]
     }, {c, Length[fns]}];

Plot[Evaluate@fns, {x, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> cd, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

```
fns = Table[{a*x, a*x^2}, {a, 5}];

psA = Table[Directive[ColorData[97, c], Thick], {c, 5}];
psB = Table[Directive[ColorData[97, c], Dashed], {c, 5}];

Plot[{Evaluate@fns[[All, 1]], Evaluate@fns[[All, 2]]}, {x, 0, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> Join[psA, psB], PlotLabels -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: ...or, use `ColorData[1, c]` (pre-version 10) or `ColorData[97, c]` (current version) to get the default colors.

Comment: @YungHummmma does this work for you?